# How to get last value in multiple rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How to select last value in multiple rows in MySQL ?

select name,date,value from table1;

```
Name    Date               Value
A       01-Jan-2013         3
A       02-Jan-2013         4
B       04-Jan-2013         2
B       05-Jan-2013         8
```

Result I need :

```
Name    Date               Value
A       01-Jan-2013         3
A       02-Jan-2013         4
        Last_value          4
B       04-Jan-2013         2
B       05-Jan-2013         8
        Last_value          8
```

How to do that in MySQL store procedure ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

There's no "last" record.  You need to sort them by the column they should be ordered by, then only select the last row.

```
/* SELECT ... */ ORDER BY sort_column DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems better suited for your Presentation Layer, but it is possible to write it using SQL.  Something like this should work using `UNION ALL` to return that last record per group:

```
SELECT Name, Dt, Value
FROM (
    SELECT Name, Dt, Value, Name Name2
    FROM YourTable 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '' Name, 'Last_Value', T.Value, T.Name Name2
    FROM YourTable T
       JOIN (
         SELECT Name, MAX(dt) MaxDt
         FROM YourTable
         GROUP BY Name
       ) T2 ON T.Name = T2.Name AND T.dt = T2.MaxDt
    ORDER BY Name2, Dt, Value
  ) t
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08dbd/1)

Resulting in:

```
NAME         DT                      VALUE
A            2013-01-01 00:00:00     3
A            2013-01-02 00:00:00     4
             Last_Value              4
B            2013-01-04 00:00:00     2
B            2013-01-05 00:00:00     8
             Last_Value              8
```

*EDIT: To get the Summed Group Total, you have to introduce the use of user defined variables.  Here is an example:*

```
SELECT Name, Dt, IF(Name='',summedTotal,Value) Value
FROM (
  SELECT @summedTotal:=IF(@prevRow=Name,@summedTotal+Value,Value) summedTotal,
    Name, Dt, Value, Name Name2,
    @prevRow:=Name
  FROM YourTable
    JOIN (SELECT @summedTotal:=0) t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT summedTotal, '' Name, 'Last_Value', T.Value, T.Name Name2, pr
  FROM (
      SELECT @summedTotal:=IF(@prevRow=Name,@summedTotal+Value,Value) summedTotal,
        Name, Dt, Value, Name Name2,
        @prevRow:=Name pr
      FROM YourTable
        JOIN (SELECT @summedTotal:=0) t
    ) T
    JOIN (
      SELECT Name, MAX(dt) MaxDt
      FROM YourTable
      GROUP BY Name
    ) T2 ON T.Name = T2.Name AND T.dt = T2.MaxDt
  ORDER BY Name2, Dt, Value
  ) t
```

And more [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb1b1/1)

Comment: @DnakkJam -- you're looking for the subtotal of each group?  that's different than how you presented above and will require use of user defined variables.

Comment: @DnakkJam - what are your desired results?  Not sure I'm fully understanding...  This should get you pretty close though...

Comment: We get last value from each group already right, so i would like to sum last value of each group.

Comment: @DnakkJam -- numbers please -- communication gap going on -- in your post you have 4 and 8 -- are you looking for 4 and 12?  Numbers please :D

Comment: @DnakkJam -- Last try, gotta run -- hope this helps :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb1b1/6 - this is based on wanting to sum 4 + 8 to get 12...

Comment: can add new row for sum last value ?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the MAX value using inner join. But you haven't specified your primary key column.

```
SELECT
  m.*
FROM mytable AS m
  INNER JOIN (SELECT
        MAX(primary_key_column)
          FROM mytable
          GROUP BY Name) AS l
    ON l.primary_key_column = m.primary_key_column
```

Comment: [SQL] SELECT m.* FROM mytable AS m INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable GROUP BY Name) AS l ON l.id = m.id

[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'l.id' in 'on clause'